# 3d tranforming/animating individual characters/words in a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to animate portions of a paragraph.
If I transform my p tag it transforms the entire box.

I've seen this done before and I'm kicking myself for not saving the stackoverflow answer to it, and now I've been searching for an answer for over an hour and can't seem to find it or any way to solve it.

Basically, I'd like the letters that the cursor hover over to pop out from the text some. I thought this could be done with CSS but javascript is welcome as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to wrap each letter in a `span`, then apply your styling when `span:hover`. The JavaScript below does this for each letter that isn't a space.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('jump').innerHTML;
var result = '';
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var char = text.substring(i, i + 1);
    if (char == ' ') {
        result += char;    
    } else {
        result += '<span>' + char + '</span>';
    }
    
}
document.getElementById('jump').innerHTML = result;
```

```css
p#jump {
    line-height: 30px;

}
#jump span:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<p id="jump">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: This is great! I think though that the animation I saw would transform not just a single letter but a radius around the cursor. I think I can edit this to make this work for me, but I would still love to figure that out as well.

Comment: A quick way to get this code to do that would be to add a [hover event handler](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) which applies a smaller transform to neighboring elements: `$(this).prev().css("transform", "translateY(-5px)");` and `$(this).next().css("transform", "translateY(-5px)");`. You'll want to make sure to unset the transform for the rest of the `spans` before applying the new transforms.